# When opening a bootstrap accordion the one next to it also changes height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a FAQ page that uses bootstrap accordion tabs. The problem is I splitted them 50/50 next to eachother but now when one tab is opened, the one next to it is opened aswell (without its content)

Example:

[image]

This is my html:

```
<div id="faqresult">
    <div class="col-md-12 animatedopen">
       <div class="vragen-wrapper">
         <div class="masonry-header">
          <h3 id="betalen">Betalen</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="masonry-vragen faqcontainer">
      
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class=" collapsed FAQ-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                  Welke betalingstermijn hanteren jullie?
                  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Bij een eerste bestelling dient er vooruit betaald te worden, hierna is eventueel betaling mogelijk op factuur.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class=" collapsed FAQ-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                  Op welke manieren kan ik betalen?
                  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>De eerste bestelling altijd vooraf, daarna eventueel betaling mogelijk op factuur. Bij een eerste bestelling of betaling vooraf wordt een inschatting gemaakt van de verzendkosten. Deze zullen op basis van nacalculatie nogmaals berekend worden. Voor het verschil in kosten kan eventueel nog een aanvullende factuur volgen.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class=" collapsed FAQ-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
                  Wanneer ontvang ik mijn factuur?
                  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse3" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>De factuur ontvang je na levering</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is it that the accordions next to the one I open, also change in height? Maybe it has something to do with the way how I split them?

I applied this CSS to have them split 50/50:

```
#faqresult{
  width:100%;
}

.faqcontainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.faqcontainer .card{
  flex: 0 0 49.5%;
}
```

Result after answer below:

Works good:

[image]

But the second one doesn't:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`align-items: flex-start;` on your *`.faqcontainer` should be solution.

> flex-start: cross-start margin edge of the items is placed on the cross-start line

align-items has default mode stretch:

> stretch (default): stretch to fill the container (still respect min-width/max-width)

**UPDATE**

You could make structure like that

```
.container
  .column_container
    .card
    .card
  .column_container
    .card
    .card
```

with css like that

```
#faqresult{
  width:100%;
}

.faqcontainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.faqcontainer .column_container{
  width: 49.5%;
}
.faqcontainer .column_container .card{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work for the second one. If I open the first one it works fine, but when I open the second one, there is space at the first one. I added an example in my question. Also I had to add it to `.faqcontainer` not `.card`.

Comment: you are right, not `.card` but `.faqcontainer`. Hmmm so maybe you should put that in another flex ? making 2 columns, that way your columns wouldnt affects each others heights